# Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<float>'

Tags: c#, linq

Hey guys i am new in c# and LINQ,i have got a following problem:

i have the following query from postgressql:

```
DataTable dt_production = new DataTable();

NpgsqlDataAdapter SumOfProduction = 
    new NpgsqlDataAdapter(@"select round(avg(m_corrected_av), 2)availability
                            from wpv.v_statistics_daily v1         
                            where   g.user_name in('" + Managers + @"')                                
                            group by 2
                            order by 1 desc 
                            limit 20", cn);         
SumOfProduction.Fill(dt_production);
```

i have the following class:

```
public class ProductionAvalability
{
    public List<float> Avalability { get; set; }
    public ProductionAvalability()
    {          
        Avalability = new List<float>();

    }
}
```

now i was looking for a way to iterate inside my datatable using LINQ like the following but i get the error i wrote in the subject:

```
var SumOfProductionToList = (from DataRow dr in dt_production.Rows
                             select new ProductionAvalability
                             {
                                 Avalability= dr["average"]                                                                                                               
                             })
                             .ToList();
}).ToList();
```

i also tried to cast it with (float) and still error which says cant convert  float to generic.list any idea?if i want to use LINQ?

Comment: Please edit your question to present your code more readably - and as a [mcve] rather than as just a set of snippets. (Hint: what does `dr["average"]` return, and what are you trying to assign it to?)

Comment: @JonSkeet ok im doing

Comment: `dr["average"]` is of type object! You cannot assign it to a `List`. The message is clear.

Comment: @JonSkeet dr["average"]  datatype could be anything,the problem is that in the linq i cant convert a datatable value to generic list

Comment: No, the compile-time return type of `dr["average"]` is very specifically `object`, and you can't assign a value of type `object` to a `List<float>`.

Comment: @JonSkeet seems like that even if i cast it to float or convert it to float

Comment: Well yes, because a `float` isn't a `List<float>`.

Comment: What are you actually trying to assign to `Avalability`? (and why is it misspelled?)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
List<float> list = (from DataRow dr in dt_production.Rows
                    select (float)dr["average"]).ToList();
```